# Font-Awesome issue: how to remove menu-link text from a menu item with font-awesome icon?

Tags: routes, theming

I installed the module [Font awesome icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome) (with it's library) & the module [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes); I've configured them, and now have a working font-icon in my main menu.

The problem is that instead of the desired icon, there is a combination of icon&Text (img1), and I need only an icon to appear... If there was an option to delete the text I would do that, But I haven't seen such an option - The menu-link text seems to be mandatory (img2).

I though of the css command `text-indent: 200px` to remove the text but the font itself is also text... Any ideas how to safely remove the text without removing the icon? Thx,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you're better off using a background image. Save yourself the hassle.

```
.menulink{
  Width: 25px;
  Height: 0;
  Padding-top: 25px; /* height of image */
  Overflow: hidden;
  Background: url(images/home-25x25.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I used one at the past and than I thought to myself to try font-awesome, but indeed a background image is simpler, though both take so much time to handle, so I'll just write a text there until (maybe in drupal 8) there will be a more efficient solution. Thanks.